# Custom category attribute load issue in admin

Tags: magento2.3

I am using Magento 2.3.2. I have created custom dropdown attribute for category. All is good until I enter admin category page. Spinner keeps spinning and in console there is error "TypeError: value.map is not a function" (file-uploader.js:79:27). 
There is something with mapping, but I can't figure out what is wrong. Did all from examples, but nothing helps. Attribute is loaded and values in dropdown also loaded. I can remove spinner from html and I can select from dropdown, even save. Issue is that spinner not removed and previously saved value is not preselected. Any ideas?

> category_form.xml:

```
<fieldset name="display_settings">
    <field name="category_icon">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Module\Vendor\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Icons</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Icon</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

> Icons.php

```
class Icons extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource{
protected $fontAwesome;

public function __construct(
    \Awps\FontAwesome $fontAwesome
)
{
    $this->fontAwesome = $fontAwesome;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getAllOptions()
{
    if (!$this->_options) {
        $fonts = $this->fontAwesome->getAllData();
        $options = [];
        foreach ($fonts as $font)
        {
             $options[] = ['value' => $font['class'], 'label' => $font['name']];
        }
        $this->_options = $options;
    }
    return $this->_options;
}

public function getOptionText($value)
{
    foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
        if ($option['value'] == $value) {
            return $option['label'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

> InstallData.php

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'category_icon', [
            'type'     => 'varchar',
            'label'    => 'Category Icon',
            'input'    => 'select',
            'source'   => 'Module\Vendor\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Icons',
            'visible'  => true,
            'required' => false,
            'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group'    => 'Display Settings',
        ]);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

**Step 1 : create InstallData.php file : Company\Module\Setup\InstallData.php
Now In this file, create an Array of the attributes that you want to add as below.**

```
$attributeGroup = 'Test Group';
        $attributes = [
            'attribute_code' => [
                'group'              => $attributeGroup,
                'input'              => 'select',
                'type'               => 'int',
                'label'              => 'Attribute Label',
                'visible'            => true,
                'required'           => false,
                'user_defined'               => true,
                'searchable'                 => false,
                'filterable'                 => false,
                'comparable'                 => false,
                'visible_on_front'           => false,
                'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front'   => false,
                'used_for_promo_rules'       => true,
                'source'                     => 'Company\Module\Model\Config\Source\Options',
                'frontend_class'             => '',
                'global'                     =>  \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'unique'                     => false,
                'apply_to'                   => 'simple,grouped,configurable,downloadable,virtual,bundle'
            ],...
          ];
```

**Step 2 : Now Add and Assign Attribute to Group and Attribute Set.**

```
// Add Attribute
// Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory  $this->eavSetupFactory
// Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup

 $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute_code => $attributeOptions) {
                $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    $attribute_code,
                    $attributeOptions
                );
            }
//Assign 
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute_code => $attributeOptions) {

                // Class \Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeManagement

                $this->attributeManagement->assign(
                    'catalog_product',
                    $attributeSet->getId(),
                    $groupId,
                    $attribute_code,
                    $attributeSet->getCollection()->getSize() * 10
                );
            }
```

**Note :**

$attributeSet : you can load the attribute collection and loop for it or Can pass specific id instead.
$groupId : Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Group : you can get the group id with the help of this class.

**Now** , Options for drop down attribute , you can add options directly as a array.
and another approach is to use class Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource  as follows :

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Model\Config\Source;

class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    /**
    * Get all options
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $this->_options = [
                ['label' => __('No'), 'value'=>'0'],
                ['label' => __('Yes'), 'value'=>'1'],
                ['label' => __('Other'), 'value'=>'2']
            ];

    return $this->_options;

    }

}
```

Please read each line carefully, so that you can create the attributes easily.

Comment: You show example of product attribute. I need to do it to category. They bit different, seems so